# CVS Update - move away file

Tags: unix, cvs

I am updating files in CVS. I put files that I needed to update in my unix folder.
Using cvs add, cvs commit - I was able to add new files to directory.
I was also able to update some from 1.1 to 1.2 using cvs update.
However I am unable to update the version for one file, getting this error:

```
cvs update filename.scr
cvs server: move away filename.scr; it is in the way
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Do what it says? Move `filename.scr` somewhere else, because your `cvs up` wants to replace it with a new version, but it either didn't exist in your currently-checked-out version or has been locally modified and not committed, so that replacing it would lose whatever changes you've made...

Answer (score 5):

Do exactly what it says - remove filename.scr.  CVS update won't overwrite the existing non-controlled copy of filename.scr.

Answer (score 1):

in the cvs hidden sub folder check if the folder of that file is on the list of entries, if so you have to add it

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, this means there's a file in the repository, and a matching file in your tree, but the file CVS/Entries doesn't mention it.  That can fail either for the CVS/Entries file at the same level as the file it's complaining about, or if you do a recursive update, it can fail due to the directory not being listed in CVS/Entries at a higher level.

This happens often to me, and I don't know why; a perfectly good checkout starts to get these errors.  If it is a missing directory, the easiest fix is to directly edit CVS/Entries, e.g. to add

D/Foo////

to Bar/CVS/Entries so that CVS knows it already owns Bar/Foo.

If it's missing a file, it's hard to regenerate the CVS/Entries line, so it's easiest to do as it says and delete the file.